# add gitlab repository to redmine :revision was not found in the repository

Tags: git, repository, redmine

I'm try add a gitlab repository to redmine, but when accessing the repository via redmine, this displays the following message:

404 :
The entry or revision was not found in the repository.

My repo configuration:

SCM : GIT

Path to repository *  : /var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories/test/project.git

i have given all permission to redmine(apache) user the folder /var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories/test/project.git

i don't want to create clone of project in redmine folder and a cron job for fetching recent changes.

Comment: Have you tried accessing the git repo outside of Redmine? It would help others with your problem.

Comment: i already tried the mirror/clone the git repo into redmine and mapped in redmine . but i don't want to create clone  repo . because we have multiple Projects and also we don't want to create an extra cron job. so i want to use same git repo